# Splitting on comma outside pair of double quotes . Ignore double quotes if it is single

Tags: java, regex, string, csv, split

I have two types of strings which i need to split using comma

First type (1" means 1 inch)

```
130,TEXT 1" 67 SERIES ,400,4,1,998,.010,9,-,7,130
```

Second Type

```
130,"TEXT, SAMPLE TEXT",400,4,1,998,.010,9,-,7,130
```

In first type i need to take string as it is and split using , 
so my split values would be 130 and TEXT 1" 67 SERIES and so on.

But in second type i need to ignore the comma between the double quotes and take the string as whole.

I split using this

```
a.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
```

which passed the second case but failed on the first. Please help

Comment: You could use a `csv` parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input format is not a valid CSV format.  According to the Wikipedia [Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) page, if quoting is used at all, a literal quote character in field **must** be quoted.

This means that it is unlikely that any existing general purpose CSV parser library will cope with both types of line in the same file.

To illustrate how deep this problem is, consider:

```
   130,TEXT 1" 67 SERIES, TEXT 2",4,1,998,.010,9,-,7,130
```

This could mean:

- one field containing `TEXT 1" 67 SERIES, TEXT 2"`
- one field containing `TEXT 1 67 SERIES, TEXT 2`, or
- two fields `TEXT 1" 67 SERIES` and `TEXT 2"`.

The only way to disambiguate this is to code some custom logic to sort it out .... based on your own business rules.

I don't think you can do this with `split` and regexes.   You need to write a proper custom parser.

But in this case, I think you would be entitled to push back on whoever / whatever is creating this CSV data.  They should be following the rules.  I would be tempted to implement my system to feed the CSV file(s) through an off-the-shelf syntax checker and automatically reject any files that fail validation.

Can you fix the errors in quoting automatically?  I think not ... in the general case.  As noted, there is no way of telling whether a double-quote in a malformed CSV is supposed to be literal or not.  It requires human intelligence, and domain knowledge to understand what the data is supposed to mean.

Comment: Yes the file is coming from a legacy system and there is no way that we can change that. Working on the logic for custom parsing for all the corner cases.

Comment: Even a legacy system can be changed.

Comment: I don't have control over those . So it cant be changed. Whatever i receive i have to process

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how (if at all) it can be done using a single regex. But here is a brute force way which counts the number of quotes in the string and go from there.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("---Type 1---");
    for (String s : split("130,TEXT 1\" 67 SERIES ,400,4,1,998,.010,9,-,7,130")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println("\n---Type 2---");
    for (String s : split("130,\"TEXT, SAMPLE TEXT\",400,4,1,998,.010,9,-,7,130")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

private static List<String> split(String str) {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    if (str.split("\"").length > 2) {
        int firstQuoteIndex = str.indexOf("\"");
        int secondQuoteIndex = str.indexOf("\"", firstQuoteIndex + 1);
        tokens.add(str.substring(0, firstQuoteIndex - 1));
        tokens.add(str.substring(firstQuoteIndex + 1, secondQuoteIndex));
        tokens.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.substring(secondQuoteIndex + 2).split(",")));
    } else {
        tokens.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

**Output**

```
---Type 1---
130
TEXT 1" 67 SERIES 
400
4
1
998
.010
9
-
7
130

---Type 2---
130
TEXT, SAMPLE TEXT
400
4
1
998
.010
9
-
7
130
```